# Batch file wait for powershell line to unzip before executing next command?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

Basically I have a Batch file that use a one lined powershell command to unzip a file, but it doesn't wait for that powershell command to finish executing. `Call` doesn't work, `start /w`doesn't work, `start powershell [cmd] -Wait` doesn't work What DO I DO?

```
cd..
start powershell Expand-Archive update.zip -DestinationPath %appdata%\ModManager\ > nul
cd %appdata%\ModManager\
[other code...]
```

Comment: See `start /?` and try this with `start /wait`

Comment: What possessed you to use `START`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use "start".  Just run powershell directly.  There are also a couple of things you need to fix in your batch file.  Replace the 2nd line with this command instead:

```
powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted -command "Expand-Archive update.zip -DestinationPath $env:APPDATA\ModManager\ | out-null"
```